# PHPMailer response json on send

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm using an email service, that will give a json response every time an email has been send.

Can the PHPMailer handle this, and if so, how?

Comment: How you are planning to do it? Any plan or attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHPMailer will only submit to local mail servers and SMTP. There is no built-in HTTP transport, but you can create messages with PHPMailer, then submit them via HTTP to whatever HTTP API you're using. For example:

```
...//construct your message
$mail->preSend();
$message = $mail->getSentMIMEMessage();
$response = http_post_fields('http://some-mail-service.example.com/api', array('command' => 'send', 'message' => $message));
var_dump(json_decode($response));
```

Obviously you'd need to alter it for the specific API, but that would be the basic idea.